# How can I use a QMap<QString, QString>::const_iterator as a pointer?

Tags: c++, qt, iterator, qmap

How can I use a `QMap<QString, QString>::const_iterator` as a pointer?

```
QMap<QString, QString>::const_iterator *i = map -> constBegin();
        while (i  !=  map -> constEnd()) {
            qDebug() << i -> key() << ": " << i -> value();

            i++;
        }
}
```

I get the error:

```
/my_class.cpp:36: error: cannot convert ‘QMap<QString, QString>::const_iterator’ to ‘QMap<QString, QString>::const_iterator*’ in initialization
         QMap<QString, QString>::const_iterator *i = map -> constBegin();
                                                                                ^
```

Comment: You *don't?* An iterator might *emulate* a pointer by overloading the dereference operators but it is no pointer by itself.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Someprogrammerdude. How else can I do it? I'm getting my `QMap<QString, QString>`  **`map`** as a pointer `*map`.

Answer (score 2):

The error is in this line:

```
QMap<QString, QString>::const_iterator *i = map -> constBegin();
                                       ~~
```

Here you are defining a *pointer* to a `const_iterator` but [`QMap::constBegin()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html#constBegin) returns just a `const_iterator`.

Simply remove the `*`, problem solved:

```
QMap<QString, QString>::const_iterator i = map -> constBegin();
```

The point is, an iterator already behaves similar to a pointer, so there is no need for the conventional syntax of defining a pointer.

Here is a [great tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/stl/iterators.html) for iterators.